# Does Apple still fix screen coating issues on the mid-2014 MBPs?

Tags: macbook-pro, screen

I read on MacRumors that if I take my mid-2014 (purchased in early 2015) 15" MBP to an Apple store, they may fix the well-known anti-reflective screen coating issue.  MacRumors is not an authoritative source, as far as I know, so I'd like to check here as well.  Anyone have info on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple has a list of current [Repair Programs](https://www.apple.com/support/exchange_repair/) on their website; unfortunately, this one is not listed.

However, a [Macworld Article](https://www.macworld.com/article/2994479/macbook/report-apple-will-replace-retina-macbook-pro-screens-with-bad-coating.html) (which references MacRumors) states:

> According to MacRumors, Retina MacBook Pro owners affected by this
>   issue will be able to get a free replacement display for up to three
>   years from the original date of purchase or until one year from
>   October 16, 2015—whichever comes last.

So, if you purchased it new in early 2015, you have until "early" 2018 to get it repaired (it sounds like you missed the window).

I would still take it to an Apple store and plead your case; it never hurts to ask.